# What the "auto" in "lib" could be used for

Tags: perl

Say I have a module which will get eventually some day on CPAN.
Is it ok to use the "auto" folder to store some default resources (templates, images etc.) that my module will use.
The user of the module may decide locally to use his own resources, but the module should work out of the box whithout needing any configurations.
Some tend to use the **DATA** section in the .pm file (even for binary data) but I prefer separate files.
Is there a convention or best practice?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the `/auto` subdirectories for that.  Use the [`File::ShareDir`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-ShareDir/) module to locate the appropriate directory for a module's shared files.

Comment: Might want to add that the other side of the story is easily handled by modules like `Module::Install::Share` and `Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ShareDir`.

Comment: Ah really helpful I looked at the source and it actually does exactly what it has to. Thanks.

Comment: If you use plain `EU::MM`, see [`File::ShareDir::Install`](http://p3rl.org/File::ShareDir::Install); if plain `M::B`, see [`Module::Build::API#share_dir`](http://p3rl.org/Module::Build::API#share_dir).

Answer (score 2):

The `/auto` directory is created by the AutoSplit.  Unless you're using that module, you should avoid it.  AutoSplit manages the `/auto` directory, so you shouldn't do anything yourself in it.

For details, see:

```
pelrdoc AutoSplit
perldoc AutoLoader
```